# Translation rule

Tags: perl, voip

I like to create a translation rule to a VoIP system to obtain the following result:
If someone dials the 4545 the system must convert this to 1234545, I managed to do this with the following rule: s/^4545/1234545/

My problem now is if someone dials 454567 my rule will convert this to 123454567 and I want to get 1234545
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear on why should 454567 become 1234545? Should a string with a run of 4545 anywhere in it be come 1234545?

If you just want to change the exact string 4545 to 1234545 then you can use `s/^4545$/1234545/`.

If you want a string with a run of 4545 anywhere in it to become 1234545 then you can use `s/.*4545.*/1234545`.

Comment: This translation corresponds exactly to my needs s/^4545$/1234545/
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
$number='1234545' if ($number eq '4545'); #eq because phone number can contain non-digits.
```

If you want to convert any number that starts with '4545', use this code:

```
s/^4545.*/1234545/
```